# Variable is automatically becoming zero after character input

Tags: c, if-statement, char

here in this program num1 value is changing into zero inside if- else condition. i am getting wrong answer as the variable is automatically becoming 0. why is that? if i give num1 as 4 and num2 as 3. i am getting added value as 3, it should be 7 right. kindly help to solve

```
#include<stdio.h>
void main()
{
    int num1, num2, answer;
    char type;

    printf("Enter num1\n");
    scanf("%d",&num1);
    printf("Enter num2\n");
    scanf("%d",&num2);
    printf("type a for addition or s for subtraction\n");
    scanf("%s",&type);

    if(type == 'a')
    {
        answer = num1 + num2;
        printf("answer is %d \n",answer);
    }
    else if(type == 's')
    {
        answer = num1 - num2;
        printf("answer is %d \n",answer);
    }
    else
    {
        printf("enter a or s");
    }
}
```

Comment: `scanf("%s",&type);` invokes *undefined behavior* - you are trying to read a null-terminated byte string into a single character

Comment: Use `scanf(" %c",&type);`. The space before the `%c` skips optional whitespace.

Comment: `add` and `sub` are undefined in if else statements. How is your code compiling?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Use `%c` for character input.
- Use `answer` variable in if-else statements.

```
#include<stdio.h>
void main()
{
    int num1, num2, answer;
    char type;

    printf("Enter num1\n");
    scanf("%d",&num1);
    printf("Enter num2\n");
    scanf("%d",&num2);
    printf("type a for addition or s for subtraction\n");
    scanf(" %c",&type);

    if(type == 'a')
    {
        answer = num1 + num2;
        printf("answer is %d \n",answer);
    }
    else if(type == 's')
    {
        answer = num1 - num2;
        printf("answer is %d \n",answer);
    }
    else
    {
        printf("enter a or s");
    }
}
```

Comment: sorry i tried multiple ways, i didnt change(add and sub) while uploading it.. i ran the code with answer variable only. your code worked. thanks. can you explain the space before %c in scanf,

Comment: Space before `%c` removes any white space (blanks, tabs, or newlines). Previous inputs can leave `\n` in the buffer so we need to remove that before taking input in character.

Comment: ok thanks , but why is that making num1 as 0.

Answer (score 0):

Solution 1:You can use %c instead of %s when receiving input from user for the type variable.

Solution 2:You can use %s to get the type variable input value. But when comparing in the if and else if statements you can use C String module's in-built function Snippet: =if(type.equals('a')). You should use equals() method for comparison in this case

```
#include<stdio.h>
void main()
{
    int num1, num2, answer;
    char type;

    printf("Enter num1\n");
    scanf("%d",&num1);
    printf("Enter num2\n");
    scanf("%d",&num2);
    printf("type a for addition or s for subtraction\n");
    scanf("%c",&type);

    if(type == 'a')
    {
        answer = num1 + num2;
        printf("answer is %d \n",add);
    }
    else if(type == 's')
    {
        answer = num1 - num2;
        printf("answer is %d \n",sub);
    }
    else
    {
        printf("enter a or s");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`add` variable used in `printf("answer is %d \n", add);` is not defined in your program. `sub` is also not. It should give a compilation error. Did you turn off compilation errors? Try this code...

```
#include<stdio.h>
void main()
{
    int num1, num2, answer;
    char type;

    printf("Enter num1\n");
    scanf("%d",&num1);
    printf("Enter num2\n");
    scanf("%d",&num2);
    printf("type a for addition or s for subtraction\n");
    scanf("%c",&type);

    if(type == 'a')
    {
        answer = num1 + num2;
        printf("answer is %d \n",answer);
    }
    else if(type == 's')
    {
        answer = num1 - num2;
        printf("answer is %d \n",answer);
    }
    else
    {
        printf("enter a or s");
    }
}
```